# Google API Calendar

Tags: ssl, curl, calendar, google-calendar-api, google-api-js-client

This is the code I have written to fetch the calendar events from Google Calendar. On running this in localhost, it takes the permission from the user but shows

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in D:\wamp\www\google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC4\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187

( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in D:\wamp\www\google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC4\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187

I tried adding cacert.pem path's in php.ini and other mentioned things over other forums. Nothing worked. I tried putting the file online in a server(Centos). Installed composer too.
But there, when I try to load the page nothing shows.

As far as I think, there the autoload.php inside vendor of Google api package does not return anything.

return ComposerAutoloaderInitd82ee48119182e2321ebd694e70287c2::getLoader();

Where am I going wrong? Or, is there something wrong with the code?

```
session_start();
require_once './google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC4/vendor/autoload.php';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . './google-api-php-client-2.0.0-RC4/src');
$google_client_id = '...';
$google_client_secret = '...';
$google_redirect_uri = 'http://localhost/gapicc.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client -> setApplicationName('Sample');
$client -> setClientid($google_client_id);
$client -> setClientSecret($google_client_secret);
$client -> setRedirectUri($google_redirect_uri);
$client -> setAccessType('online');
$client -> setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
$googleImportUrl = $client -> createAuthUrl();
if(isset($_GET['code']))
{
    $auth_code = $_GET['code'];
    $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
    $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
    $calendar_service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
    $calendar_list = $calendar_service->calendarList->listCalendarList(array())->getItems();
    echo json_encode($calendar_list);
}
```

echo filter_var($googleImportUrl, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL); // Path where I am heading the user when he clicks "Import Google Calendar"

Comment: Have you looked at the [PHP Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/php) for Google Calendar API? Is the Calendar API enabled in your developer console?

Answer (score 0):

It's ok to use URL without SSL as redirect URL. localhost is also allowed. 
The problem probably in auth or token URL

1. Check *Restrictions* of you key here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials
2. Try to use credentials.json from there instead set ClientID and ClientSecret.
   It also has auth_uri and token_uri.

   For this use fresh google API calendar quickstart https://github.com/gsuitedevs/php-samples/tree/master/calendar/quickstart as help with all steps.

   with the last version of google API (2.2.2 now) 
   https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-php-client/releases